# Meaning of ticker symbol suffixes for Toronto Stock Exchange listings

Tags: stocks, canada, toronto-stock-exchange, ticker-symbols

When looking at the ticker symbols of stocks listed on the Toronto Stock Exchange (TSX and TSXV), I noticed that there are many kinds of suffixes. For example, ".A", ".DB", ".H", ".PS", ".PF", ".PF.A", ".U", ".UN", ".RT", ".WT", etc. What do these suffixes mean? I could make these guesses: ".A" means "class A ordinary shares", ".PF.A" means "class A preferred shares", ".UN" means "units", ".WT" means "warrants", but I want to be really sure. Is there an authoritative reference for this?

Answer (score 2):

- TSX extensions :

A-B – class of shares

NO, NS, NT – notes

S – special U.S. terms

DB – debenture

P – Capital Pool Company

U, V – U.S. funds

E – equity dividend

PR – preferred

UN – units

H – NEX market

R – subscription receipts

W – when issued

IR – installment receipts

RT – rights

WT – warrants

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: [Source 1](https://support.quotemedia.com/support/solutions/articles/13000074165-symbol-suffixes-behind-the-dot-and-fifth-letter-extensions)
[Source2](https://www.quotemedia.com/quotetools/symbolHelp/SymbolHelp_US_Version_Default.html)